# Facebook Winlogon.exe MSN Gaming Zone virus

Tags: virus, facebook

My daughter clicked on a baitFacebook posting and now we believe that our PC is infected with a Virus that is sending out similar bait postings to her friends.

I narrowed it down to a folder

C:\Program Files\msn gaming zone\windows

I am unable to delete the folder,so I used an app Unlocker to show me what file or folders are locked:

[image]

If I kill winlogon.exe, my PC blue screens.

I can delete the folder in safe mode, but the folder restores itself.So far, I cannot identify the process responsible for putting this folder back in place.

Any idea where this winlogon.exe actuallyresides? The \??\path is strange.I believe that the winlogon.exe is a required file. could it have REPLACED Microsofts so that it performs the same required function but also injecting virus behavior?

I need help in getting rid of this muffer.

Answer (score 1):

WinLogon is the process that allows you to log in on Windows; if you kill it, you see the BSOD, as you noticed.
The executable is in `C:\WINDOWS\System32`.

A UNC starting with `\\?\` is called [long UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) (or UNCW); `\\?\C:\WINDOWS` is equivalent to `C:\WINDOWS`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the program is not locked in Safe Mode, it is likely that it is not running then - this should make it easier to remove. You could try running an up-to-date antivirus scan on your hard drive in Safe Mode; this might find the other malicious software on your computer that is restoring the malicious folder.

Here are some auxiliary tools that might help if your antivirus program has issues:

- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - Task Manager on steroids, and with pretty colors.
- [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) - shows you programs, DLLs, and other executables that start up automatically
- [Rootkit Revealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445.aspx) - shows files with strange attributes, which may be caused by a [rootkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit).

Answer (score 0):

I've applied the diagnostic tools and still have the same result that the "msn gaming zone" directory keeps getting re-created.  Do you have a definitive way to fix this issue? I'm unable to replace winlogon.exe as its a basic windows process.
Thanks, Dave

Comment: Perhaps some spyware byproduct? Run an antivirus and a spyware remover.

Comment: msn gaming zone isn't malware.  Furthermore the author was killing winlogon.exe  and getting a BSOD which is to be expected when you kill a system process.